# Options in Scala with Boolean default value with getOrElse

Tags: scala, scala-option

I have a map with some pairs and I want to assign a default value(Boolean) for a key, the default value for a key is a string when I used getOrElse and I'm looking for a way to do it for a int or boolean.

for Eg:

```
val someMap= Map("key1"->"value1", "key2"->3, "key3"-> true)
//let's see if I want to get the key `key4` with a default value of false using getOrElse
val key4= someMap.getOrElse("key4", false) //which I couldn't achieve.
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: it shows as it accepts only string not a boolean value in getOrElse.

Comment: I ran your code with Scala 2.13 and it compiled and ran without any problem producing a `key4 :Any = false` result.

Comment: yeah I got the same in when I ran in console, how ever when I tried in my code it's giving me this.:
 error: type mismatch;
[ERROR]  found   : Any
[ERROR]  required: Boolean

Comment: `val someMap` is type `Map[String,Any]` so it can't be used in any context requiring a `Boolean`.

Comment: you can always cast the result to boolean -which may not be a good idea depending on your use case- by adding a `.asInstanceOf[Boolean]`.

Comment: You shouldn't have an **Any** in the first place. That is a code smell. Why do you need a `Map[String, Any]` wouldn't a normal class _(or a case class)_ work better? Or maybe, you are trying to model something like a **JSON**?

Answer (score 4):

It works well on scala 2.12 in scalafiddle, not sure why it does not in your case:
https://scalafiddle.io/sf/uzZNFH5/1

In addition you can use `withDefaultValue` to simplify your map (it will always return specified value for non existing keys)

```scala
val someMap:Map[String, Any] = Map("key1"->"value1", "key2"->3, "key3"-> true).withDefaultValue(false)
```

You can also use `withDefault` which gives you possibility to map non existing key to expected value.

But I still agree with others that using Map[String, Any] isn't perfect solution on the first place :(.

**EDITED**

Ok... From comments I see your problem is that you just cannot USE returned value because it is Any not Boolean. You can do something like that:

```scala
//first option
someMap.get("key4").map {
  case x:Boolean => x
  case _ => true //or whatever should be taken when answer is string
}.getOrElse(false)

//second option
val someMapV:Map[String, Boolean] = someMap.mapValues {
  case x:Boolean => x
  case _ => true //or whatever should be taken when answer is string
}.withDefaultValue(false)
//Oh... and keep in mind that mapValues is lazy... without good reason. //You should not use any side effects using it !!! 


someMap("key4")
```

Comment: unfortunately, My application is written in 2.11.

Answer (score 2):

Let's make it a bit more rigorous. One of the options is to use a sum type (aka coproduct) to type-safely define what's in the map:

```
sealed trait Value
case class StringValue(value: String) extends Value
case class IntValue(value: Int) extends Value
case class BooleanValue(value: Boolean) extends Value
val someMap: Map[String,Value] = Map("key1"->StringValue("value1"), "key2"->IntValue(3), "key3"-> BooleanValue(true))
val key4= someMap.getOrElse("key4", BooleanValue(false))
```

P.S. to avoid these a bit ugly case classes, you can use [scalaz.Coproduct](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.scalaz/scalaz-core_2.11/7.2.4/scalaz/Coproduct.html) or even somethig like [iota](https://github.com/frees-io/iota).

Answer (score 0):

This is because someMap is of type `Map[String, Any]`. I would suggest implementing custom method

```
implicit class SettingsMapOps[K](anyMap: Map[K, _]) {
  def isEnabled(key: K): Boolean = anyMap.get(key).map {
    case b: Boolean => b
    case _ => false
  }.getOrElse(false)
}
```

So given your example the code `someMap.isEnabled("key3")` will return `true` and all others will be false.